# identfying listview cell on mouseover

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to identify which cell the user has their mouse over on a listview, currently I have

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    Dim cellnum As ListViewItem = ListView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
        tooltip1.SetToolTip(ListView1, thisItem.Text)
end sub
```

which is not functioning. How would I accomplish this

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5270/ListView-with-Item-Hover-Event ? Also this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemmousehover(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "cell" you mean the subitem, use HitTest to find the subitem:

```
 Dim ht As ListViewHitTestInfo = lvex.HitTest(pt.X, pt.Y)
 if ht.Item IsNot Nothing then
      IndexOfSubItemAtXY = ht.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(ht.SubItem)
 End if
```

Setting the tooltip on a MouseMove may prove problematic though.  There is an ItemMouseHover where you could figure out which cell/subitem, it is over and set the tooltip accordingly/

Comment: I am having difficulty figuring out the declarations for some of these variables

ByVal pt As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs I assume for pt

what should I declare subitem and item as

Comment: I just checked and mine is, but it only fires only on ITEM hover...move across subitems and it does not reset or refire.  the `Pt` would be `e.X` and `e.Y` from most mouse events

Comment: what about "SubIndex" and "Item"

Comment: item == dt.item and subindex is the index of the subitem it is over (see edit).  look at MouseHover as well - you should be able to tell which subitem there and get a new event each time the mouse hovers

Comment: ok, this is sucessfully getting me a column index, how do I find the row too

Comment: I've tossed out several things, so I dont know what path you are going down, but if you examine the contents of `ListViewHitTestInfo`  you'll see ITEM is a member ("row"), so `Item.Index" would be the item/row index, but if you have the item, maybe just use Item.Text?